# Включение шаблонов и std::enable_if

Tags: c++, функции, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Это пример кода с сайта cppreference.com. Какой из трех вариантов включения перегруженных вариантов foo является предпочтительным? Я, помнится, где-то сталкивался с утверждением, что один из них уязвим, т.е. можно передать аргумент ф-ии во втором случае, кажется.

И вообще, как понимать корректно этот синтаксис? В первом случае понятно, там второй параметр - тип, он возвращается как тип возвращаемого значения у функции. А случаи 2 и 3 - как forward-declaration для типов? Например, второй случай: `(T t, TYPE* = 0)` - запись примерно такая, т.е. какой `TYPE` мы получим? `void` видимо. А что будет, если пытаться передать в эту функцию второй аргумент?

Аналогично вопрос про третий случай - как понимать запись `class = ...`?

А в случае с классом, я так понимаю, тоже `void` в случае успеха получаем и ошибку компиляции иначе. Не совсем четко понимаю, зачем это нужно `template<class T, class Enable = void> class A`.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

// Включение перегруженных вариантов foo1 при помощи возвращаемого типа
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type
    foo1(T t)
{
    std::cout << "foo1: float\n";
    return t;
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type
    foo1(T t)
{
    std::cout << "foo1: int\n";
    return t;
}

// Включение перегруженных вариантов foo2 при помощи дополнительного неиспользуемого параметра
template<class T>
T foo2(T t, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value >::type* = 0)
{
    return t;
}

// Включение перегруженных вариантов foo3 при помощи дополнительного параметра шаблона
template<class T ,
         class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type >
T foo3(T t) // обратите внимание, сигнатура функции не меняется
{
    return t;
}

// Включение объявления класса A при помощи дополнительного шаблонного параметра
template<class T, class Enable = void>
class A; // еще неопределенный (undefined) класс

template<class T>
class A<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value >::type> {
};

int main()
{
    foo1(1.2); // OK, будет вызвана первая версия foo1()
    foo1(10); // OK, будет вызвана вторая версия foo1()

//  foo2(0.1); // ошибка времени компиляции
    foo2(7); // OK

//  A<int> a1; // ошибка времени компиляции
    A<double> a1; // OK
}
```

Comment: @Abyx объясните, пожалуйста, как синтаксис понимать. Вопросы 2 и 3 абзаца. Они все связаны, я писал, как в голову приходило непонимание. С уязвимостью уже сам разобрался.

Answer (score 5):

Длинный ответ на длинный вопрос.
Здесь используется SFINAE (Substitution failure is not an error).
Ошибка при подстановке параметра шаблона (substitution failure) не будет ошибкой компиляции (an error), а всего лишь удалением данной потенциальной перегрузки из возможных кандидатов.

> И вообще, как понимать корректно этот синтаксис? В первом случае понятно, там второй параметр - тип, он возвращается как тип возвращаемого значения у функции. А случаи 2 и 3 - как forward-declaration для типов?

Тип `std::enable_if<>::type` определён только для `std::enable_if<true>`.
Этот тип определяется как второй параметр шаблона. Значение по умолчанию для второго параметра шаблона - `void`.
Т.е. `std::enable_if<false>::type` всегда не определён для любого или отсутствующего второго параметра (substitution failure), `std::enable_if<true,T>::type` - имеет тип `T` или `void`, если второй параметр явно не указан.

Обратите внимание, что синтаксис требует `typename` перед именем типа, зависимого от параметров шаблона.

В случае шаблонов функции `foo1` тип результата `std::enable_if<>::type` будет определён как второй параметр std::enable_if (здесь второй параметр - тип T, но можно указать любой тип, в т.ч. и void) только в тех случаях, когда первый параметр `std::enable_if` `true`, т.е. только если `std::is_floating_point<T>::value==true` для первого случая и `std::is_integral<T>::value==true` для второго. В остальных случаях эти определения шаблонов `foo1` использоваться не будут.

Для `foo2` вводится дополнительный аргумент функции. Тип аргумента определён как указатель на некий тип `std::enable_if<>::type`, который, как и в предыдущем случае, либо определён для позитивного первого парамера шаблона `std::enable_if<true>::type` (второй параметр шаблона, значение по умолчанию - `void`), либо неопределён (substitution failure).
Имя аргумента пропущено, значение аргумента по умолчанию - `= 0` (лучше бы `= nullptr`), т.е. при вызове фактический аргумент не потребуется.

> А что будет, если пытаться передать в эту функцию второй аргумент?

Если первый аргумент будет не интегрального типа, то тип указателя для второго арумента не будет определён, подстановка будет неуспешной, независимо от наличия или значения второго аргумента. Для первого аргумента интегрального типа если второй аргумент приводим к `void*`, то подстановка успешна, но аргумент просто не будет использован в самой функции, но если тип второго аргумента неявно не  приводится к `void*`, то подстановка тоже не будет успешной.

> Аналогично вопрос про третий случай - как понимать запись class = ...?

Для `foo3`, как и написано, сигнатура функции не изменяется, а вводится уже не фиктивный аргумент функции, а фиктивный неименованый параметр шаблона (имя параметра пропущено). Этот параметр - типовой, что обозначено словом `class`. Вместо слова `class` чаще стали использовать `typename`.
Для этого параметра устанавливается определение типа по умолчанию (=), которое, опять же, определёно только для позитивного первого параметра `std::enable_if`.

Если при вызове функции явно указать оба параметры шаблона `foo3`, например, `foo3<double,void>(3.0)`, то можно форсировать применение  данного шаблона, даже в том случае, если первый параметр `std::enable_if` будет негативным, т.е. для `std::is_integral<double>::value==false`.

> Какой из трех вариантов включения перегруженных вариантов foo является предпочтительным?

Вечный вопрос: Bug or feature? Особенности при явном использовании фиктивных параметров/аргументов в `foo2` и `foo3` можно и использовать. Общих правил нет. Лично я предпочитаю стиль `foo1`.

> Не совсем четко понимаю, зачем это нужно `template<class T, class Enable = void> class A`.

Это, собственно, шаблон класса, просто объявление, что имя `A` относится к шаблону класса и имеет указанные параметры, без этого ссылаться на `A` нельзя.

```
template<class T, class Enable = void>
class A;
```

Оба параметра - типовые, для второго задано умолчание - `void`. Имена параметров не обязательны и нужны только тогда, когда на них ссылаются.

Далее приводится частичная специализация ранее объявленного шаблона класса `A` для типов с плавающей запятой:

```
template<class T>
class A<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value >::type>{
};
```

> А в случае с классом, я так понимаю, тоже `void` в случае успеха получаем и ошибку компиляции иначе.

Подстановки `A<double>` и `A<float>` будут успешными, будут использованы определения этой специализации, а например, подстановка `A<int>` не будет успешной для специализированного шаблона, но допустима для самого объявления шаблона `class A`.

Таким образом, само по себе, использование `A<int>` не будет ошибкой.

```
A<int> a1; // ошибка времени компиляции
```

Ошибка в указанном случае будет вызвана попыткой конструирования переменной типа, для которого даже размер не определён, но допустимо, например:

```
extern A<int> const volatile* p;
```

Этот указатель можно использовать там, где вообще можно использовать указатель на не полностью определённый тип (например, как фактический аргумент функции).

Answer (score 1):

> Какой из трех вариантов включения перегруженных вариантов foo является предпочтительным? Я, помнится, где-то сталкивался с утверждением, что один из них уязвим, т. е. можно передать аргумент ф-ии во втором случае, кажется.

Последний вариант с дополнительным шаблонным параметром тоже позволяет подставить этот параметр извне и обойти проверку. Так что методом исключения получаем, что первый вариант (оборачивание возвращаемого типа в `enable_if`) наиболее защищённый.

> И вообще, как понимать корректно этот синтаксис? В первом случае понятно, там второй параметр - тип, он возвращается как тип возвращаемого значения у функции.

В первом случае написан не просто тип возвращаемого значения. Там обёртка вида `std::enable_if<условие, тип>`, где `условие` — шаблонный параметр типа `bool`. Особенностью этой обертки является то, что её `typedef`-поле `type = тип` определено только при `условие == true`. На эту особенность и полагается условно доступная перегрузка (обратите внимание — у каждого из вариантов в объявлении так или иначе задействовано это поле).

Чем же примечательна эта особенность? А тем, что попытка сослаться на несуществующее поле (что произойдёт в случае `std::enable_if<false, ...>::type`) не даст породить шаблонный вариант метода, из которого было упомянуто это поле.

> Например, второй случай: (T t, TYPE* = 0) - запись примерно такая, т. е. какой TYPE мы получим? void видимо. А что будет, если пытаться передать в эту функцию второй аргумент?

Ничего. Это фиктивный параметр, единственное назначение которого — хоть как-то упомянуть поле `std::enable_if::type`.

> А в случае с классом, я так понимаю, тоже `void` в случае успеха получаем ...

Да, так как у `std::enable_if<условие, тип>` шаблонный параметр `тип` по умолчанию задаётся в `void`.

> ... и ошибку компиляции иначе.

Тоже верно — см. выше про попытку обращения к несуществующему полю `type`.

> Не совсем четко понимаю, зачем это нужно `template<class T, class Enable = void> class A`.

Это так называемая *частичная специализация*. То есть мы сначала определяем общий случай (приведённый вами класс без полей), а затем — специализацию (у которой `std::enable_if` на месте `class Enable`). Суть этого действия в том, что компилятор всегда будет предпочитать специализацию. Общий же случай же будет выбран только в случае невозможности её порождения.